# Problemas en la instalacon de laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente problema, luego de instalar *laravel* introduzco el comando `php artisan serve` para acceder al servidor y me da el siguiente error:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\prueba/vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\prueba\artisan on line 18
>
> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\prueba/vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\prueba\artisan on line 18
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\prueba/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\prueba\artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\prueba/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\prueba\artisan on line 18

la verdad no se que pueda ser... espero su ayuda.

Comment: Ejecuta composer install en el proyecto, y verifica que tengas php 7.2 mínimo.

Comment: ya lo ejecute y si tengo php 7.2.2

Comment: Ya me funciono el comando pero ahora me da error 500 cuando ejecuto el servidor en el navegador

Comment: Eso es otro error distinto, probablemente algo en el código está mal, se sale del alcance de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Probablemente no has instalado las dependencias respectivas del proyecto, ejecuta:

```
composer install
```

en la raíz del proyecto, y si estás instalando una versión reciente de Laravel (6+), confirma que tienes instalado php7.2